# How to add code to vendor folder manually

Tags: composer-php, vendor

I need to clone a project of my company on my local machine.

Problem: There is a module required in the main **composer.json** from our old agency which does not exist anymore, so I don't have the access keys needed to download it, BUT I have the latest code of that module.

The composer.json of that module says its name is "randomagency/import", so I added the code at `vendor/randomagency/import`. Then I removed the module from the main composer.json.

But I get this error:

```
Class 'RandomAgency\ProcessPipelines\Helper\Condition\AbstractCondition' not found#0 /var/www/company/src/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(444): include()
#1 /var/www/company/src/vendor/composer/ClassLoader.php(322): Composer\Autoload\includeFile()
#2 [internal function]: Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader->loadClass()
#3 [internal function]: spl_autoload_call()
```

My colleague told me that I need to add the module in the main composer.json under the [autoload](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload) section, but Im not sure how exactly it works.

---

The best approach to solve it would be to create a new composer package and replace the agency URL in composer.json with my own, but I need a quick & dirty method for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't put it into *vendor* (as it is expected to get removed in time and the name of the [`vendor-dir` is a configuration detail](https://getcomposer.org/doc/06-config.md#vendor-dir)), so technically you have already put it in the wrong location. However, this is easy to recover from, just use a different path *within* the project root directory, e.g. create a directory where you put packages into (`pkg` in the following). This works already with autoloader configuration only (if that library requires no other configuration to work):

### PSR-4 Autoloader (only) from Project Directory

Then add that path to the projects autoload configuration (see [autoload (Composer configuration schema) - Autoload mapping for a PHP autoloader.](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#autoload):

```json
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
           "RandomAgency\\Import\\": "pkg/random-agency-import-4.2"
        }
    }
}
```

It's good practice you have a single folder for the package - not two as in `<vendor>/<package>` pattern - and append an identifier of the package version.

### Require as Composer Package from Project Directory

Better thought, if that package still contains the `composer.json` configuration file, add it as a [*path repository*](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#path) and require it with a version constraint that matches the `./pkg/random-agency-import-4.2/composer.json#/version`  or `*` if the "version" member is missing:

```json
{
    "require": {
        "random-agency/import": "*"
    },
    "repositories": [
        {
            "type": "path",
            "url": "./pkg/random-agency-import-4.2"
        }
    ]
}
```

You then don't need to configure the autoloader manually as it is taken from the libraries `composer.json` configuration. This is equally true for any other configuration part incl. the dependencies of the library.

The great benefit of the *path* repository is, that is accepts *relative* paths to your projects configuration file (composer.json).

Compare with your previous understanding:

> The best approach to solve it would be to create a new composer package and replace the agency URL in composer.json with my own, but I need a quick & dirty method for now.

You either have solved it by now (the package you require has a composer.json file) or you still need to add the package information, but you don't need to create a *new* package or exchange URLs.

### Package Repository: Inline a Composer Package from Project Directory

That is because you can inline the package as well in Composer with the [*package repository*](https://getcomposer.org/doc/05-repositories.md#package-2) that now has the *`path`* and if you look at `/repositories/0/package` closely, you can see that this is another `composer.json` document, just inline at that place (and the `/dist` member is new):

```json
{
  "repositories": [
    {
      "type": "package",
      "package": {
        "name": "random-agency/import",
        "version": "4.2.0",
        "dist": {
          "type": "path",
          "url": "./pkg/random-agency-import-4.2"
        },
        "autoload": {
          "psr-4": {
              "RandomAgency\\Import\\": ""
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ],
  "require": {
    "random-agency/import": "4.2.0"
  }
}
```

When you do updates etc., Composer then will install the packages files into the vendor folder (where-ever it may be, and regardless how often you remove it).

If - and only if - there is no `./pkg/random-agency-import-4.2/composer.json` file, you would need to create a "package", as that is the `composer.json` in the end.

#### Alternative: compser.json within the package directory

Similar as you added the autoload part to `composer.json` and as an alternative to the *package repository*, you can create the `./pkg/random-agency-import-4.2/composer.json` file your own, then the *path repository* already suffices and it is perhaps easier to configure / maintain as the roots project composer.json file does not expand all the package details.

But that is your preference, just showing that you have a couple of options within the project itself without creating outside / "new" packages.

Comment: Thank you for your time to write this detailed explanation :)

Comment: You're welcome. Thanks for your nice feedback @Black. And never underestimate when thinking "easy" that there is after getting it to work one more iteration - here I gave two. You'll benefit when the configuration fits the tooling. I think I'd put a composer.json in the packages folder within the projects history (path repository) for getting this flying.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Had to add it like this:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "RandomAgency\\Import\\": "vendor/random-agency/import"
    },
```